# Combining multiple keys to create a Synthetic partition key in Cosmos db

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using below code to upload my document in Cosmos Db and I need a partition key which I have to create by combining two key. in this case it will be TypeId and Cvalue. I would like to know how can i create a Synthetic Partition key in my code below. Thanks

```
var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>( lines );
var client = new DocumentClient( new Uri( DbInstance ),Key );
await client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                Database, Collection ),
                content);

    "Classes": {
        "Subjects": {
          "Name": "testA",
          "TypeId": "AS88QW",
          "Public": "No"
        },
        "Sections": {
          "Scopes": true,
          "CValue": [12,12,1]
        }
      }
```

Comment: David said exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly specify multiple different properties as a combined synthetic partition key. You'd need to do the combining yourself, into another property. In your case, you'd be creating a new property that combines `Classes.Subjects.TypeId` and `Classes.Subjects.CValue`. Then that new property (whatever you decide to call it) can be specified as your partition key.

Just note that there's nothing automatic here: you need to create this new property when creating your documents. And you'll need to figure out how to represent something like an array (your `CValue` property) - how you want to turn that into part of the partition key's value.

You can find more information about synthetic partition keys [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/synthetic-partition-keys#concatenate-multiple-properties-of-an-item).